# Convert Between Digest::MD5.digest and Digest::MD5.hexdigest

Tags: ruby

How do I convert a hash string originally encoded with `Digest::MD5.digest('abc')` to a hex string in the following format `Digest::MD5.hexdigest('abc')`? The difference is that the hex string is safe against different encoding issues (regardless of the encoding it is read in).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using then [unpack](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2011/07/20/ruby-pack-unpack.html) method will do the trick. ([Checkout the official documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-unpack))

```
Digest::MD5.digest('http://www.example.com').unpack('H*').first == Digest::MD5.hexdigest('http://www.example.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string = Digest::MD5.digest('abc')
Digest.hexencode(string)
```